Is there any way to play multiple audio in better_player - flutter?
Here is my code to play video from memory, that is an in app video. Is there any way to play multiple audio in better_player like netfix or youtube? The video is saved in the memory of the device and it fetches the file.
class MemoryPlayerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? filePath;

  const MemoryPlayerPage({
    super.key,
    this.filePath,
  });

  @override
  MemoryPlayerPageState createState() => MemoryPlayerPageState();
}

class MemoryPlayerPageState extends State<MemoryPlayerPage> {
  late BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    BetterPlayerConfiguration betterPlayerConfiguration =
        const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
      controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
        enableAudioTracks: true,
      ),
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    );

    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(betterPlayerConfiguration);
    _setupDataSource();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _setupDataSource() async {
    File file = File(widget.filePath!);
    List<int> bytes = file.readAsBytesSync().buffer.asUint8List();
  BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource.memory(bytes,
        videoExtension: "mp4", useAsmsSubtitles: false, useAsmsTracks: true);
    _betterPlayerController.setupDataSource(
      dataSource,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Memory player"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Text(
              "Memory player with plays video from bytes list. In this example"
              "file bytes are read to list and then used in player.",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            child: BetterPlayer(controller: _betterPlayerController),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried the detailed code for playing video in better_player and need to play it in my app only
